# Need help on deployed contract!

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I have a token contract that is already deployed in the mainnet, Is it possible for me to inherit the properties of that contract for my new contract that is going to implement the use-cases for the deployed token.

My doubts are,

1. Is it possible to write a new use-case contract inheriting the properties of the old contract..?
2. Do I need to deploy the token contract again to achieve it..? Or is it possible by deploying the new contract from the same address where the token contract got deployed..?

Please let me know the best approach..

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if you mean that;

you can use interface contract to inherit pre-contract

[image]